# Use \' in mysql in like close

Tags: mysql

{ When i execute this query it return empty result but result is save in data base with         `enter code here`first name is D\'Ami

```
SELECT u.UserFirstName, u.UserLastName, u.UserHasLoginAccess, u.UserEmail
FROM Users u
WHERE u.UserLicenseID =  '1603'
AND TRIM( u.UserEmail ) !=  ''
AND (
u.UserEmail LIKE  "%D\'Ami%"
OR u.UserFirstName LIKE  "%D\'Ami%"
OR u.UserLastName LIKE  "%D\'Ami%"
OR CONCAT_WS(  ' ', u.UserFirstName, u.UserLastName ) LIKE  "%D\'Ami%"
)
LIMIT 0 , 50}
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c375/2

Answer (score 0):

when you want to search for single quotes using query, you must escape it with another single quote and not `\`. eg

```
u.UserEmail LIKE  "%D''Ami%"
OR u.UserFirstName LIKE  "%D''Ami%"
OR u.UserLastName LIKE  "%D''Ami%"
OR CONCAT_WS(  ' ', u.UserFirstName, u.UserLastName ) LIKE  "%D''Ami%"
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for reply                                                      actual in data base first name is save in this format D\'Ami  but when i am using in like query it is not returning any result my question is that how write query that return result with name D\'Ami